# Making a scythe more effective / feasibility of the Scythe

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons

Consider the [scythe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_scythe), and it's importance in mythology (i.e, the Grim Reaper) and its usage in [anime](http://blog.honeyfeed.fm/top-10-anime-scythe-users/). However, it does not seem to be very effective in real life. Is there any way to make the scythe more dangerous ? (adding poison is allowed)

Comment: [Lindybeige](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rzQwzg5_mo)

Comment: If I really wanted to kill someone (I don't) and the only thing that was around was a lollipop, I'd try to stab him in the throat with the stick.  There is a difference between "can it be used at all" and "can it be used as well as something conventional."  It sounds like you are more interested in the second question, but can you clarify, please.

Comment: The scythe is an agricultural tool, a perfect image for the reaper of souls. As a result, it's not really a dueling weapon, but it's plenty deadly... How about a kama, which is basically a hand scythe/sickle? Those are famously used as weapons by eastern monks, so they certainly fill the lethal role...

Comment: There are also forward curving blades similar to a scythe such as the [falx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falx).

Comment: Remember that the large majority of wars have been fought by formations of poorly trained militia. The big sweeps and spins you see in anime would be impossible in formation and would be a detriment to your unit. That is why they were more often turned into [makeshift pikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_scythe#/media/File:Polish_scythemen_1863.PNG) as in the page you linked.

Comment: I did not realize that this was a duplicate .... damn -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scythe is a tool designed for cutting at nearly ground level. Not ideal if you want to be cutting about 5 foot up.

The first thing you're going to do is straighten the blade relative to the handle, maybe even face it entirely in line with the handle rather than at 90deg.

At this point you realise you've started with entirely the wrong tool as what you've just created is better known as a billhook (they come with long and short handles) which is basically a polearm with a civilian name.
[image: billhooks]

As you can see from the above image, the billhook, unlike the scythe, is very much still in use to this day. It's far easier to use and is much more versatile.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I didn't realize that this question was a duplicate lol. Still, you get a +1 from me